# Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in logcat

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I've faced with a disaster. I created a registration/login part for my application using MySql and PHP. now when I try to register in my own system, the logcat says:

```
    08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at ir.homa.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:124)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at ir.homa.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:116)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-06 10:43:24.161 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-06 10:43:56.734 2792-2800/ir.homa W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.598ms
08-06 10:46:38.102 2792-2800/ir.homa W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.298ms
08-06 10:48:12.053 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-06 10:48:12.053 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-06 10:48:12.053 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
08-06 10:48:12.053 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
08-06 10:48:12.053 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at ir.homa.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:124)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at ir.homa.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:116)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 10:48:12.061 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-06 10:48:12.062 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-06 10:48:12.062 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-06 10:48:12.062 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-06 10:48:12.062 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-06 10:48:12.062 2792-2792/ir.homa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-06 10:51:42.807 2792-2800/ir.homa W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.424ms
```

Here is my php codes ->

register.php:

```
    <?php

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['phonenumber'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["usernames"]["username"] = $user["username"];
            $response["usernames"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["usernames"]["phonenumber"] = $user["phonenumber"];
            $response["usernames"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["usernames"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (username, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

login.php:

```
    <?php
require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["users"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["users"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["users"]["phonenumber"] = $user["phonenumber"];
        $response["users"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["users"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "user is not found with the credentials";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "required post params is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

DB_Functions.php:

```
    <?php



class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new username
     * returns username details
     */
    public function storeusername($username, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usernames(unique_id, username, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at, phonenumber) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $username, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt, $phonenumber);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $username = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $username;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get username by email and password
     */
    public function getusernameByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $username = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying username password
            $salt = $username['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $username['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // username authentication details are correct
                return $username;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check username is existed or not
     */
    public function isusernameExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from usernames WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // username existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // username not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Here is my java codes ->
AppController.java:

```
package ir.homa;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 6/16/2016.
 */

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {


    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

RegisterActivity.java :

```
package ir.homa;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 6/17/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private EditText inputPhoneNumber;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        inputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneno_editText);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);


        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    HomaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String phonenumber = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();


                if (!username.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(username, email, password, phonenumber );
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "لطفا اطلاعات خود را وارد نمایید!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String username, final String email,
                              final String password, final String phonenumber) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("در حال ثبت اطلاعات ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "وضعیت ثبت نام: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("unique_id");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("usernames");
                        String username = user.getString("username");
                        String phonenumber = user.getString("phonenumber");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(username, email, uid, created_at, phonenumber);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "با موفقیت ثبت نام شدید! برای ورود لمس کنید.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "خطا در ثبت نام: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("phonenumber", phonenumber);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java:

```
package ir.homa;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 6/17/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject users = jObj.getJSONObject("usernames");
                        String username = users.getString("username");
                        String email = users.getString("email");
                        String phonenumber = users.getString("phonenumber");
                        String created_at = users.getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(username, email, uid, created_at, phonenumber);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                HomaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Thank U for helping and humanity!

Comment: Please add your json data

Comment: My json data are adding by registerActivity inputs

Comment: What do you get when you call login/register ? (JSON String)

Comment: Just this error.. Value <br of type ... and nothing haven't been added to database

Comment: What is your mean ?

Comment: Your server is sending you an error in html instead of the JSON you are expecting.  Log it and see what the error is, then fix it!

Comment: I checked but haven't any html code in my server

Comment: The HTML isn't "in" your server it's "from" your server.  An error is occurring on your server, and the server is returning an HTML error page.  You need to either log the response, or reproduce it from a context where you can see the response, such as a browser.  Did you look at the link Daniel Nugent supplied you?

Comment: @nasch my problem has been solved.. please post your answer then I will vote u.. thank u all... #AlokPatel #DanielNugent